# ng-include in mdDialog not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, mddialog

I am trying to use a single modal dialog function to house multiple templates. I send the call to create the dialog box an input and I am trying to call various ng-include files based upon that input. However, it seems that the ng-include files are never called.

Is there something I am missing?

Dialog Call

```
function showDialog(ev, thisItem, modalType) 
    {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: 'DialogController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/views/templates.html',
            locals:{
                modalType : modalType
                thisItem : thisItem
            },
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            fullscreen: true
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            vm.selectedRef=data;
            // Call to server to update the references
        }, function() {

        });
    };
```

The template that should be calling the various lower templates

```
<md-dialog aria-label="" id="marginDialog" class="dialogItem" ng-cloak>

<span ng-if="vm.modalType=='bibEdit'"
      ng-include="app/main/apps/views/editReference.tmpl.html">

</span>

<span ng-include="app/main/apps/templates/editMargins.tmpl.html">

</span>
```

I can confirm that the variables reach the template and are correct and that they are correct in the controller. However, the include files are simply not called.

Answer (score 0):

I've had really mixed results mixing ng-includes with angular material components, so generally I try to avoid it now.

What I would try to do in this case is write a function that determines the correct template url, and then pass that as the dialog config object:

```
function showDialog(ev, thisItem, modalType) 
{
    var template;
    var getTemplate = function(){
      switch(modalType){
        case 'one':
          template = 'dialog1.html';
          break;
        case 'two':
          template = 'dialog2.html';
          break;
      }      
    }();

    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'DialogController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: template,
        locals:{
            modalType : modalType
            thisItem : thisItem
        },
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose:true,
        fullscreen: true
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        vm.selectedRef=data;
        // Call to server to update the references
    }, function() {

    });
};
```

Here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZJKzq?editors=1010#0)

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I am not sure if I should accept it since there doesn't seem to be a clear answer that ng-include is / isn't allowed with the mdDialog?

Comment: The Angular Material doesn't not specifically mention it, but that doesn't mean there aren't bugs. I find the documentation to be still new and somewhat lacking. If you go to the Github repo for Angular Material, you'll see a lot of reported bugs, and many revolve around ng-include.

Comment: Actually. I just noticed your file path. Try adding single quotes around the file paths like this: `ng-include="'app/main/apps/views/editReference.tmpl.html'">`. Im not sure why, but sometimes that works in my code too.

Comment: I'll take a look at that later today. If that's it, it would be nice to have it working, but a real pain for such a simple issue.

Comment: It appears that it was the single quotes that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive. That works inside an md-dialog.

```
(function() {

    // Add the directive to the module
    angular.module("YourApp").directive('editMargins', EditMarginsFactory);

    // Factory Method
    function EditMarginsFactory()
    {
        // Construct and return the instance
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false,
            templateUrl: "app/main/apps/templates/editMargins.tmpl.html"
        };
    }

})();
```

Then, instead of using ng-include in your other template, just do this:

```
<edit-margins></edit-margins>
```

Note that the use of **scope: false** in the directive causes it to use the parent scope, the scope used by the template you added the directive to.